# Why do Haskell's typeclass laws have to be verified manually?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Why does one need to explicitly write checks (possibly using quickcheck) for type class laws in Haskell?

For example for testing associativity of the String monoid:

```
leftIdcheck :: Monoid a => a -> Bool
leftIdcheck a = a <> mempty == a

quickCheck (leftIdcheck :: String -> Bool)
```

But this is so much work! Why can't the haskell complier just check all this by default on its own and tell me that my instance of monoid on my type doesn't satisfy the identity law ?

Is there any library or language extension that allows us to have these checks built in as we write the program instead of having to write them separately? This seems very error prone.

On a related note, does Agda let us have these checks/proofs for free or do we have to write them manually there too?

Comment: Because in general one can not verify this. This is a consequence of Rice's theorem.

Comment: QuickCheck tries to find bugs trying a few random values. It does not try all of them since in general there are infinitely many values. Computability theory indeed proved that perfect automatic verification of semantic properties (e.g., laws) is impossible. What Haskell, however, could do is to provide QuickCheck properties for all classes and laws so to facilitate testing. I am not aware of any library providing this, but in principle it could be written.

Comment: OK, it is impossible to have an algorithm that _certainly_ succeeds to prove the required property “in general”. But is it impossible to provide an algorithm that is allowed to fail but succeeds for some simple cases ? Like, the compiler is supposed to be able to derive instances of the `Eq` class in simple situations, so the compiler can apparenty convince itself of properties such `x == x` and/or `x==y && y==z  ⇒  x==z`. And that saves a lot of boilerplate code. Of course, it is perfectly OK if it fails for things such as `newtype NTei = NTei (Int -> Int) deriving Eq`.

Comment: @jpmarinier the compiler doesn't give any “thought” about stuff like `x==x`, when deriving an `Eq` instance. It just has some hard-coded rules about how equality from types `A` and `B` implies equality on `(A,B)` and on `Either A B`, and that extends inductively to equality on any algebraic data type.

Comment: @chi, there are Andrew Martin's `quickcheck-classes` and the earlier `checkers` and `genvalidity-hspec`. I don't know the trade-offs among them, except that Martin's is likely a bit easier to use.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Haskell is a non-total language without dependent types, therefore most properties you might want to prove **a)** can't even be *formulated* exactly **b)** aren't *really* strictly speaking true, if you consider ⊥.

In Coq and Agda, that is a different story, and indeed a Coq class will normally contain not only the methods its Haskell pendant has, but also the *laws*:

```
Class Monoid (m: Type) : Type :=
  { mempty : m
  ; mappend : m -> m -> m
  ; mempty_left : forall (p: m), mappend mempty p = p
  ; mempty_right : forall (p: m), mappend p mempty = p
  ; mappend_assoc : forall (p q r: m)
                  , mappend p (mappend q r) = mappend (mappend p q) r
  }.
```

Still that doesn't mean the compiler will just automatically prove those for you, when you declare an instance. As Willem Van Onsem commented, that is in general impossible. You need to write the proof yourself, and that is much, *much* more laborious than writing a QuickCheck property. Of course if you've managed to do it, it *is* a bit more reassuring, however in practice QuickCheck is usually enough to catch >90% of all bugs. Proper formal verification is great, but it's only worthwhile for really important / safety-critical code and even then it's quite a good idea to first let QuickCheck confirm that there's even any *hope* of proving what you're trying to prove.